# PHP MVC rendering home page

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, structure, partial-views

I'm trying to learn MVC design pattern for web applications so I decided to write my own PHP MVC framework. Before writing this post I read a lot of tutorials and forums about MVC. Now I pretty well understanding the MVC idea, and how communicate controller-model-view. I have write router and few modules (login, categories, ...) - seems it's working.

Now I'm confused  a bit:

If I call `localhost/LogIn` I get only login form, if I call `localhost/categories` I get category list. Everything OK, but I want to create index controller and when calling `localhost/index` I want see login form, categories and a lot more modules.

Should I call controllers (login, categories) from `indexController.php`?

I need advice how to concatenate needed modules in one page.

Comment: Do not call from executed controller another. Create list functional of category on model of category. Or U may create standalone class which will be create lists of models (category, post etc). But If U create modules (it's not controller) U may call it how U are like; And, please, do not new bycicle :) Use Yii, Codeigniter, kohana...

Comment: Thanks for comment. I know about Codeigniter, kohana, symfony, and other framework. if i need real system, i use one of them, now i writing only for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, controllers shouldn't be calling each other's functions. Some frameworks introduce "[helpers](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/55212/)" to implement what you need.

Controllers can use the same models, and views anyway are going to be different, so you can use your Categories model to provide you categories to display (e.g. $categories->getCategoriesList()) and then using it in category controller view and also in index controller view.

A legitimate method of calling one controller from another is by forming an HTTP request - e.g. receiving an HTML snippet (another controller rendered view) to display in your view via AJAX or using an iframe with a source pointing to your another controller (which is a clumsy solution, mostly for idea illustration).

Answer (score 0):

You need several things:

1. You need a .htaccess file that will cause all requests to go through your index file, here is a simple one:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /demo
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```
2. In the index.php file you need to set the include path, so you won't have to explicitly include the modules/controllers/views or any other class you choose:

   ```
    define("APPLICATION_PATH", realpath('.'));
    $paths = array(
       APPLICATION_PATH.'/controllers',
       APPLICATION_PATH.'/models',
       APPLICATION_PATH.'/views',
       APPLICATION_PATH.'/libs',
       APPLICATION_PATH.'/includes',
       get_include_path()
   );

   set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
   ```
3. now add the 'magic method' for autoloading classes (called automatically) and initialize your Bootsrap class:

   ```
   function __autoload($className){
   $fileName = str_replace('\\','/', $className);
   require_once "$fileName.php";
   }
   new Bootstrap();
   ```
4. Bootstrap.php:

   ```
   <?php
   class Bootstrap {

       public function __construct() {

           $url = $_GET['url'];

           $params = explode('/', $url);

           //if controller exist - call it, else call login controller
           if (isset($params[0]) && $params[0]){
               $controller = new $params[0]();
           }
           else{
               $controller = new login();
           }

           //if method exist - call it, else call index method
           if (isset($params[1]) && $params[1]){

               //if parameter exit - call method with param, else call witout param
               if (isset($params[2]) && $params[2]){
                   $controller->$params[1]($params[2]);
               }
               else{
                   $controller->$params[1]();
               }
           }
           else{
               $controller->index();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

That should give you a basic MVC Framework.

Comment: Hey, I like your answer. For 300 points, could you look at my question and tell me what you think. If your answer is the best (helps me the most) you will get the 300 points. I may have the vocabulary wrong because I am still learning MVC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works

Comment: What would `$url` generally look like if this RewriteRule is used, `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`? I only mention it because one must be wary of the `//` in the url scheme (`http://` or `https://`)

Answer (score 0):

Use your controller (index.php) to centralized code that would be used on every page (request validators, error handles, exception handlers, session stuff).

Create a Router class to get the correct models. Allow the models to get the correct views. I have included some UML diagrams from my other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works) to help out. Remember, try to program to an abstract interface, not to a concrete implementation.

[image: Router UML Diagram]

[image: Model UML Diagram]